# How to give blackberry application all the available permission?

Tags: blackberry, permissions

I'm developing using JDE 4.5 which doesn't contain the PERMISSION_RECORDING,
and it's denied by default in 4.6 and higher devices.

So I want my application to have this permission or all the possible permissions that it can get.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't set app permissions pro grammatically. What you can do is force Request Permission dialog to appear, see [How to - Display custom messages in the request permission dialog](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/832062/How_to_-_Display_custom_messages_in_the_request_permission_dialog.html?nodeid=1577553&vernum=0)

So what you can do is do some test recording on application startup, then Request Permission dialog will come up. It would come up anyway, but on startup this will be more in place, and more, you can set your own message text there.

**UPDATE**
If permission is set to Deny than there will be no Promt Dialog on denied action.
Then you can use ApplicationPermissionManager to invoke permission request:

```
ApplicationPermissionsManager manager = ApplicationPermissionsManager
    .getInstance();
int current = manager
    .getPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_SCREEN_CAPTURE);
if (current != ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW) {
    ApplicationPermissions permissions = new ApplicationPermissions();
    permissions.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_SCREEN_CAPTURE);
    manager.invokePermissionsRequest(permissions);
}
```

Comment: The recording permission is denied by default so there's no prompt appear in using the recording API.

Comment: Thanks for your update, but the problem is the constant that represent the recording (PERMISSION_RECORDING) doesn't exist in JDE 4.5.


When I looked at JDE 4.6 documentation I saw that the PERMISSION_SCREEN_CAPTURE is  seprecated. As of 4.6, replaced by PERMISSION_RECORDING.

SO in JDE 4.5 the permission that represent the recording is PERMISSION_SCREEN_CAPTURE, so I used it to allow recording voice and it's working.

Comment: You saved me a lot of time, thank you. My app scans QR code and I was experiencing device lockup at first run of my app and I wasn't aware of the existence of ApplicationPermissionsManager.