# How to set application permission programmatically in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, permissions

What I want is avoid the Permission interface that pop up while install an application instead manually provide all the permissions in programmatically. Is that a do-able thing in BlackBerry development. If so please give me a hint, how to do that.

Already I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699873/how-to-give-blackberry-application-all-the-available-permission). But that is not what I am looking for. I don't want user to see that Permission interface at all.

Comment: In short, no. It would be a serious security flaw if the apps were able to grant permissions themselves. But if the devices are inside a corporate BES, then the BES admin can manage permissions remotely.